# проблема с вызовом пакета XLConnect в R

Tags: r

Почему у меня при попытке вызвать пакет `XLConnect` выскакивает сообщение об ошибке:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’
```

Хотя я установила  все запрашиваемые  в  данном сообщении пакеты?

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке написано - нет переменной окружения `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас не установлены Java и Java JDK. Или не указаны их директории в переменной среды Path, если используете Windows.

При этом лучшим решением с точки зрения скорости, устойчивости и удобства в R для работы с xlsx файлами, на мой взгляд, является пакет `openxlsx` - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf